# Adding 80-column wide comment header block with centered text

Tags: alignment, comments, ascii-art

For some reason or another I often divide the code into subsections separated by headers like these:

```
################################################################################
#################################### LOAD ######################################
################################################################################
```

These are 3 80-column wide lines of `#` with a title centered in the middle.
So far I haven't find a quick way to generate these in vim.

What I usually do is something along the lines of `80i#` and then `yypp` to give me 3 lines, but then I need to navigate to the middle and add text. I usually do this with replace, but replace does not center the header inside `#`…`#` So I delete the excess of `#`'s manually.

How to center the text in the middle row? And what would be a faster way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a slightly more efficient / easier method. Type it with the cursor at the beginning of the line of text (i.e. `LOAD`) that you want to center.

- `:center 80<cr>`: center the text with Vim's built in function
- `hhv0r#`: add the `#`s on the left
- `A<space><esc>40A#<esc>`: add plenty of `#`s on the right
- `d80|`: delete excess `#`s on the right
- `YppVr#kk.`: add top and bottom `#`s

So, the full command:

```
:center 80<cr>hhv0r#A<space><esc>40A#<esc>d80<bar>YppVr#kk.
```

You could put something like this in your .vimrc in order to add a convenient mapping:

```
nnoremap <C-b> :center 80<cr>hhv0r#A<space><esc>40A#<esc>d80<bar>YppVr#kk.
```

Mini-screencast demonstration:

[image: demonstration]

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to `:set expandtab`.

1. `80`<kbd>i</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to create the top line
2. <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to duplicate it
3. <kbd>O</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>`LOAD`<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>
4. `:center 80` (The `80` may be omitted, depending on your `textwidth` setting.)
5. <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> to fill the left side (using visual select and replace)
6. <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to fill the right side (by duplicating some characters from the bottom line)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a vimscript function for that.

```
function Header(width, word)
    let a:inserted_word = ' ' . a:word . ' '
    let a:word_width = strlen(a:inserted_word)
    let a:length_before = (a:width - a:word_width) / 2
    let a:hashes_before = repeat('#', a:length_before)
    let a:hashes_after = repeat('#', a:width - (a:word_width + a:length_before))
    let a:hash_line = repeat('#', a:width)
    let a:word_line = a:hashes_before . a:inserted_word . a:hashes_after

    :put =a:hash_line
    :put =a:word_line
    :put =a:hash_line
endfunction
```

And it could be called like

```
: call Header(80, 'Hello')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really great answer. Works for any number of lines and can even be modified to include other characters (not only #) easily. Shame I can only give 1 upvote and accept only a single answer. This time I had to go with the one I am more familiar with (and writing functions - I am not familiar with that, but thanks to you I see how they work).

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use visual blocks:

1. Make sure you already have at least three blank lines at the top, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>80</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>
2. <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>#</kbd>
3. Move to the middle of the block (you're going to have to eyeball this)
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and select the area of the block you want to remove
5. <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>
6. Go to beginning of empty space, hit <kbd>R</kbd> and type your header.

Granted, it's not the most perfect way to create a header, as you have to eyeball it, but it's an interesting case for the Visual Block selection.

Result

```
#################################################################################
##########################    this is a header      #############################
#################################################################################
```