# How to generate random numbers?

Tags: text-generation

I would like to generate one or few random numbers separated by new line.

How this can be done?

Comment: Pure vim? Or, say, using `:python`?

Comment: Pure vim preferred, but if it's not build-in, any easy memorable method is fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Starting with Vim [8.1.2342](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2342), you can make use of the `rand()` and `srand()` functions.

Here is an example:

```
let g:seed = srand()
echo rand(g:seed) % 100   " to echo a random number between 0-99
```

For older Vims, you'll have to fall back to calling some external commands (or use the Python, Perl, Tcl, MzScheme, Ruby, Lua language interfaces, if your Vim comes with those enabled).

---

### UNIX Shell (`/bin/sh`)

Calling:

```
strings -n 1 < /dev/urandom | tr -d '[:space:]' | head -c15
```

with `system()` is a good way. You can get only numbers by replacing `tr` with `grep`:

```
strings -n 1 < /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:digit:]]' | head -c15
```

You can use this in Vim like so:

```
:echo system("strings -n 1 < /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:digit:]]'  | head -c15")
```

The number 15 is the amount of numbers you want (adjust accordingly). This should work on Linux, BSD, OSX, and other UNIX systems. It won't work on MS Windows.

Also see my weblog post "[Generate passwords from the commandline](https://www.arp242.net/cli-passwords.html)" (there are a lot of bad solutions for this out there).

### Ruby

Ruby is probably the next best choice, since Ruby scripting seems to be a bit more common than Python scripting. Getting a random number is easy:

```
:ruby puts Random.rand(10)
```

Or to get 15 numbers:

```
:ruby 15.times { puts Random.rand(10) }
```

### Python

You can use the [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module; to get a single number:

```
:py import random; print(random.randint(0, 9))
```

Or a 15 numbers:

```
:py import random
:py for i in range(0, 15): print(random.randint(0, 9))
```

This should work for both Python 2 & 3.

### Windows PowerShell

You can use [`Get-Random`](https://web.archive.org/web/20151104185850/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/04/27/get-random.aspx)
to get a random number:

```
:echo system('Get-Random')
```

### Windows `cmd.exe`

Windows 7 and later should ship with PowerShell, but if you want maximum
compatibility you can use `cmd.exe`. It has a special variable `%RANDOM%`:

```
:echo system('@echo %RANDOM%')
```

Note: [This is not very random!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100617-00/?p=13673)
, it uses the time (!)

---

Note that you don't need to use the Ruby or Python bindings to use the Ruby or
Python solutions; you could also create a separate script and call them with
`system("python -c '...'")` (this does require that ruby/python is installed,
obviously.

Comment: Instead of `tr -d '[:space:]'`, perhaps `tr -cd '[:digit:]'` for the grep filter?

Comment: @muru I'm not sure that will work on OSX, which is why I didn't use it... You also get the numbers seperated by a newline this way, like the OP asked....

Comment: If that's the case.... GNU beats BSD. :P

Comment: One can also use the shell (system) for inputting random numbers, i.e. `:r! hexdump -n $((3*4)) -e  '"%d"' /dev/urandom`, would generate 3 random signed integers.

Comment: @HAL9001 Your example doesn't work (at least on OSX, doesn't paste anything). However on shell returns sometimes like: `444204315-1248057303-74280604`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Example `:echo system(...` is just printing on the screen, can you modify the example to paste into the editor?

Comment: @kenorb This will correctly use the shell for inputting 3 signed random integers: `:r! hexdump -n $((3*4)) -e '"\%d\n"' /dev/urandom`

Comment: @HAL9001 I think using `%u` as a format would be better, since that's unsigned? This should remove negative numbers & the associated `-` character ... Also, why not just type `12` insyead of `$((3*4))`? That way it will work in *all* shells...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The multiplication is to emphasize that the numbers come in 4 byte packages, and yes, depending on the context `%u` may be better suited.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a **pure vimscript** solution. I did not create it, it was developed by Charles E. Campbell. You can find a Github repo with his code [here](https://github.com/posva/Rndm).

---

The algorithm uses 3 seeds generated at Vim startup and generate a pseudo-random number based on calculations and permutations applied to the seeds:

```
" Randomization Variables
" with a little extra randomized start from localtime()
let g:rndm_m1 = 32007779 + (localtime()%100 - 50)
let g:rndm_m2 = 23717810 + (localtime()/86400)%100
let g:rndm_m3 = 52636370 + (localtime()/3600)%100
```

The variables scope is declared as global because they are used by the generator function but it could be restricted to the script (`s:`)

And here is the generator function:

```
function! Rndm()
    let m4= g:rndm_m1 + g:rndm_m2 + g:rndm_m3
    if( g:rndm_m2 < 50000000 )
        let m4= m4 + 1357
    endif
    if( m4 >= 100000000 )
        let m4= m4 - 100000000
        if( m4 >= 100000000 )
            let m4= m4 - 100000000
        endif
    endif
    let g:rndm_m1 = g:rndm_m2
    let g:rndm_m2 = g:rndm_m3
    let g:rndm_m3 = m4
    return g:rndm_m3
endfun
```

---

The repo includes the following functions:

- A "randomish" initialization of the seeds;
- A way to read some user-defined seed from a text file;
- A pseudo random generator
- Several random functions:

  - A function that generates a random number within a range
  - A dice rolling function
  - A function to randomly swap a list of sequential integers

---

Here is a quick test I wrote to test the generator: I generated 1000000 numbers between 0 and 9 and counted the number of occurrences of each number here are the results:

```
0 : 100409
1 : 99435
2 : 100433
3 : 99578
4 : 100484
5 : 99948
6 : 100394
7 : 99649
8 : 99803
9 : 99867
```

As you can see the generation seems to be well distributed. I'm aware that this is largely not enough to test a random generator so I'll try to make some extra analysis if I have some free time.

Answer (score 8):

This is a method found in the [vim-randomtag](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-randomtag) plugin, which is based on reading ... current time microseconds, usable when you just want *some* number, you don't care much about randomness quality, or have security concerns etc.:

```
function! s:randnum(max) abort
  return str2nr(matchstr(reltimestr(reltime()), '\v\.@<=\d+')[1:]) % a:max
endfunction
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`rand()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#rand()) and [`srand()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#srand()) functions, provided your Vim binary includes the patch [8.1.2342](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2342).

---

As an example, to generate 10 random numbers separated by newlines:

```
let seed = srand()
echo range(10)->map({-> rand(g:seed)})->join("\n")
```

To generate 10 random numbers all inferior to 100:

```
let seed = srand()
echo range(10)->map({-> rand(g:seed) % 100})->join("\n")
```

To generate 10 random alphabetical strings of 5 characters:

```
let seed = srand()
echo range(10)
   \ ->map({-> range(5)
   \           ->map({-> (97+rand(g:seed) % 26)->nr2char()})->join('')})
   \ ->join("\n")
```

To generate 10 random words (taken from the dictionary file `/usr/share/dict/words`):

```
let seed = srand()
let words = readfile('/usr/share/dict/words')
let len = len(words)
echo range(10)->map({-> g:words[rand(g:seed) % g:len]})->join("\n")
```

To generate 10 sequences of 5 random words:

```
let seed = srand()
let words = readfile('/usr/share/dict/words')
let len = len(words)
echo range(10)
   \ ->map({-> range(5)
   \           ->map({-> g:words[rand(g:seed) % g:len]})->join()})
   \ ->join("\n")
```

To generate a random UUID version 4:

```
" Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38191078/9780968
let seed = srand()
let random_numbers = range(30)->map({-> rand(g:seed) % 16})
echo call('printf', ['%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x-%x%x%x%x-4%x%x%x'] + random_numbers[:14])
 \ ..call('printf', ['-X%x%x%x-%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x%x'] + random_numbers[15:])
 \   ->substitute('X', '89ab'[rand(seed) % 4], '')
```

To apply a random color scheme:

```
let seed = srand()
let colorschemes = getcompletion('', 'color')
let len = colorschemes->len()
exe 'colo '..colorschemes[rand(seed) % len]
```

Answer (score 4):

Vim doesn't offer native random generator, however if you have vim compiled with Python, the following method will append a random digit at the end of your line:

```
:py import vim, random; vim.current.line += str(random.randint(0, 9))
```

<sup>Note: To check if your vim supports Python, try: `:echo has('python')` (1 for yes).</sup>

You can also use shell which offers `$RANDOM` variable (works with bash/ksh/zsh) which returns a pseudorandom (0-32767), in example:

```
:r! echo $RANDOM
```

or:

```
:put =system('echo $RANDOM')
```

or:

```
:r! od -An -td -N1 /dev/urandom
```

<sup>On Windows, you've to have Cygwin/MSYS/SUA installed, or use `%RANDOM%` variable as [Carpetsmoker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/812/467) suggested.</sup>

If you don't have access to shell and Python, as for workaround, you use last few digits from the current timestamp, in example:

```
:put =reltimestr(reltime())[-2:]
```

<sup>Note: If you're using it quite often, write a simple function which will `return reltimestr(reltime())[-4:]`.</sup>

> Note: Above methods returns only a pseudorandom integer which should not be used to generate an encryption key.

---

To add more random numbers please press <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to repeat the command again. Or prefix with number (like <kbd>10</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>) to add much more of random numbers separated by new lines.

---

Related:

- [VIM generate random numbers in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430493/vim-generate-random-numbers-in-the-buffer) at stackoverflow
- [Generate random number in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/generate-random-number) at stackoverflow

Comment: It also works with `zsh`, but not with `sh`, `dash`, `fish`, `csh`, or `tcsh` ... You could use `:r! bash -c 'echo $RANDOM'` ...

Comment: *"return last few digits from the current timestamp"* -> This is not random. Using the time to get a pseudo-random number is almost always a bad idea, *even* for non-crypto purposes. What if the timestamp's resolution is in seconds and you create a "file.$random" twice in a second? Oops! ... Plus, you never know when someone's going to use your `GetRandom()` function where good prng *does* matter, so it's better to just get it right from the start if possible (and it's almost always possible here!)

Comment: I don't know what the quality of `$RANDOM` is, but if this is a poor PRNG then that's not a reason to use an even poorer PRNG :-) Instead, upgrade to a better PRNG! As far as I know, `/dev/urandom` is available on all platforms where `bash` is commonly available, so I don't see a reason to *not* use it.

Comment: I didn't know about `$RANDOM`. Seems like a very nice little tool, and even though it may be a "poor's man RNG" (as @Carpetsmoker points out), it definitely fits @kenorb's (who asked the question) requirement of "easily memorable".

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a native function for random numbers in Vimscript.

A way using `:python` (use it in a function, perhaps, with 10000 and 60 replaced by parameters):

```
:python <<EOF
import vim
import random

line = vim.current.window.cursor[0]
r = getattr(__builtins__, 'xrange', range) # To make it work for both Python 2 & 3
vim.current.buffer[line:line] = list(map(str, random.sample(r(10000), 60)))
EOF
```

See my answer to [Making a box in vim via python](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/474/making-a-box-in-vim-via-python/585#585) for a quick intro on Python scripting in Vim.

Since `vim.current.buffer` is a list of strings, we can assign a list of strings to it the way we would in Python. [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) is just the simplest way I can think of to get a list of random integers in Python.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) repuires only two arguments on Python 2, [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=str#str) is the builtin function to convert things to strings. Let me look up the Py3 equivalents (`str` would be the same, will have to check `xrange` and `random.sample`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker aargh, typo. The bracket after 60 is supposed to be after 10000. And `xrange` is not in Python3 because `range` is equivalent (neither actually constructs a list, unlike `range` in Py2).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker And the final difference is that `map` in Py3 returns an iterable and not a list, so the last line would use `list(map(str, random.sample(range(10000), 60)))`

Comment: Okay, I've taken the liberty to edit your post with some (minor) changes to make it compatible with both Python 2 and 3...

Answer (score 2):

Vim [v8.1.2342](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2342) add `rand` and `srand` function.

I prefer this way to generate 20 random numbers in range 0-100 in current buffer:

```
:put =rand()%100
20@:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use a source outside your computer, [random dot org](https://www.random.org/integers/?mode=advanced) will do. The command line is  a bit not-easily-remembered, so I'd put it in a shell script, but this will give you twenty four-digit decimal random numbers.

`:r!curl -s "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=20&min=1000&max=9990&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new"`