# Does Vimscript have an official name?

Tags: vimscript, history-of, terminology

The name of the language sometimes known as Vimscript is a topic of debate. Some places use Viml (or is it VimL?), others Vimscript. Does it have an official name, and if it does, what is it and since when is it official?

- [SO question on VimL vs Vimscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4398312/2072269) (~5 years old)
- [A recent post mentioning that it has got an official name](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3834/205)

A run of `:helpgrep \cviml\>` leads us to [`syntax.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#g%3Avimsyn_noerror):

```
                                                        g:vimsyn_noerror
Not all error highlighting that syntax/vim.vim does may be correct; VimL is a
difficult language to highlight correctly.
```

And [`version7.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/version7.txt.html#better-python-interface):

```
Added special python-vars objects also available for python-buffer and 
python-window. They ease access to VimL variables from Python.
```

So it would seem `VimL` is the *official* term, yet [`usr_41.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html), the file that best documents the language, doesn't have any mention of `VimL`.

Answer (score 13):

The name *VimL* appeared in the documentation [in July 2013](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/fae66b13ff51f3c35832245dc2e43aa81b0d944f#diff-c1daf587351a4db5b6b54f1a86a5dd27). Vim's scripting language didn't have a name before that.

*VimL* is the only name mentioned in the documentation. It doesn't really make it the official name but, well… that's the closest we have.

FWIW I don't like it and will probably keep calling it vimscript for some time.

Comment: Well, let's change it then! ... grimscript? :P

Comment: Curious: has Bram Moolenar (did I spell that right?) ever discussed this in the mailing lists?

Answer (score 2):

I paste here my answer on SO ...

`:h usr_41.txt` says *Vim script language* for the language, and *Vim script(s)* for ..., well, scripts.

VimL can be used as an abbreviation for *Vim script language*.

Comment: Considering that two other files in the documentation use VimL without explanation, does either paragraph have any substance worth being in an answer?

Comment: Thus they says both are valid names for vim scripting language. Either way, _VimScript_ has never been an official name for what we are speaking about.