# How to append a random number between a range [1,10] at the end of each line in Vim?

Tags: line-breaks, enumerate

I have a graph data in a file with each line containing the source and destination node of an edge. I want to assign a random weight between [1, 10] for each edge to test my graph algorithm. How can I do that in Vim?

**Graph data:**

> 1 2 
> 2 3 
> 1 5

**Data along with weights(Expected Output)**

> 1 2 5
> 2 3 3
> 1 5
> 9

The last column is the weight of each edge.

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430493/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-the-buffer to see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a macro :

```
:r!echo $RANDOM^Mld$kJ
```

Decomposing the macro :

```
:r!echo $RANDOM^M
```

**Note** : `^M` is the litteral `<CR>`, so you should press `<CR>` instead of `^M` when you record your macro.

This insert in a new line a random number (you should look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20430735/2558252) for more infos).

```
l       " go right
 d      " delete ... 
  $     " ... to the end of the line (leaving only the first digit)
   k    " go up
    J   " join the line below
```

**Note** :
As stated by @Doorknob :

> Bash's $RANDOM returns a random number from 0 to 32767

So to keep the last digit instead of the first one, you can replace the `ld$` part by : `vehx`. I think that a random number generation should be put in a function and be carefully handled.

Comment: The above macro is generating a random number with 4 or 5 digits. Along with the numbers the characters "^Mld" is appended. But it is not appending to the end of the line. It is creating a new line. I guess the commands ld$ and kJ is not working. Is there any dependence where those commands might not work?

Comment: The `^M` stands for the litteral `<CR>`, I edited my answer to be more clear. I don't understand why the `ld$kJ` part doesn't work as it's basic vim commands ...

Comment: -1, this is very, very far from random. Bash's `$RANDOM` returns a random number from 0 to 32767, so your results will be heavily biased towards 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: I didn't know that, let me update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't mind the quality of the random process generation:

```
:%s/\s*$/\=' ' . (1 + str2nr(matchstr(reltimestr(reltime()), '\v\.@<=\d+')[1:]) % 10)/
```

It basically replaces the end of each line, and all the trailing spaces, with a single space followed by `(current time microseconds % 10) + 1`, where `%` is the remainder/modulo operation.

[random ... reference](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3832/1800)

Answer (score 0):

This is the gist of it (assuming UNIX environment):

```
:g//read! echo $RANDOM
:g//join
```

If you want the number to be between 1 and 10:

```
:g//read! echo $(( 1 + $RANDOM % 10 ))
:g//join
```

If you want to do this for a section of the file, just select the lines in visual line mode before typing the first command, and press `gv` before typing the second.

Comment: Did you miss the $ for the pattern in :g command?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It works.