# How to generate patterns for comments?

Tags: vimscript, comments

As a way of organizing my codes, I like to include some titles as comments with specific patterns (I wish I can add ASCII art!). Consider for example, putting the following to mark a specific block of code:

```
//===================== Solving a big problem =============================//

//--------------------The most important calculation-----------------------//
     ... some code ...
//------------------------End of the calculation---------------------------//

//--------------------I/O operations are on their way ---------------------//
     ... some code ...
//------------------------End of I/O operations----------------------------//
//============================== End solution =============================//
```

What I require:

1. The pattern should be 80-column wide (including identation space)
2. The title should be centered

Is there a way I can automate the generation of such patterns in vim?

Comment: I wrote a little plugin "blockit" (https://github.com/sk1418/blockit) to generate some header texts (comment could be done as well) with alignments, width, border characters as options , it may not work exactly as what you want, but you can check the codes to do some adjustment.

Answer (score 8):

**Please don't do that**: This type of title comments is just too heavy and
doesn't improve the readability of your code. If you really need to create a
section use light multi lines comments like:

```
"
" Solving a big problem
"
```

That's much easier to read. So now that I gave my totally subjective opinion,
which you don't have to agree with:

**Here's a function to let you do what you want**

```
function! MyComment(...)

    " get the arguments properly 
    if (a:0 == 0) 
        let argString = "" 
        let argChar = "-" 
    elseif (a:0 == 1) 
        let argString = a:1 
        let argChar = "-"
    elseif (a:0 == 2) 
        let argString = a:1 
        let argChar = strpart(a:2, 0, 1)
    else 
        echom "Too many arguments" 
        return
    endif

    " Get the characters to use at the beginning and the end of the title
    let result = substitute(&commentstring, "commentstring=", "", "") 
    let resultList = split(result, "%s") 
    let Comment = resultList[0] 
    if (len(resultList)>1) 
        let EndComment = resultList[1] 
    else 
        let EndComment = Comment
    endif

    " create the comment title 
    let nb = (80 - strlen(argString) - len(Comment) - len(EndComment)) / 2 
    let i = 0 
    let commentString = argString

    while i < nb 
        let i = i + 1 
        let commentString = argChar . commentString . argChar
    endwhile

    " append one more char if necessary 
    if strlen(argString) % 2 != 0 
        let commentString = commentString . argChar 
    endif

    let commentString = Comment . commentString . EndComment

    " Put the title in the buffer 
    exe ":normal o" 
    exe ":normal i" . commentString

endfunction
```

You can call the function in 3 different ways:

- `:call MyComment()` will insert an "empty title" of 80 characters like this:
  `//-------------------------------------------------------------------//`
- `:call MyComment("Title section")` will insert a title with the default `-`
  character like this:

  `//--------------------------Title section----------------------------//`
- `:call MyComment("Another title", ".")` will let you choose the character to
  repeate in your title *(If the second string contains more than one
  character, only the first one will be used)*:

  `//...........................Another title............................//`

Also with this function if you are editing a `C` file, using `:call
MyComment("Hello world")` will insert:

```
/*--------------------------------Hello world---------------------------------*/
```

In a `java` file you'll get:

```
//--------------------------------Hello world---------------------------------//
```

And a `php` file:

```
/*--------------------------------Hello world---------------------------------*/
```

**Improvements**

- For now the function doesn't takes into consideration the indentation level,
  if I get motivation I'll edit my answer otherwise I'll let it as an exercise
     for the reader ;-) *(remember that you can get the indent level of a
         line with `:foldlevel(x)` [this
         page](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/49.html)
         might help)*.
- It would also be possible the create a command to shorten the call of the
  function, this tricky part might be to handle the optional number of
  arguments.

---

**EDIT** In the comments @Peter Rincker suggested [a much more elegant solution
than mine](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/6e16e5a82065d7f9809f). With his
authorization I'll present here a new version inspired by his function and the
explanation of the different tricks he used:

```
function! MyComment(...)

    " get the arguments properly
    let commentText = get(a:000, 0, '')
    let commentChar = get(a:000, 1, '-')[0]

    " Get the number of char to add on left
    let len   = (80 - len(commentText) - len(printf(&commentstring, '')))
    let left  = len / 2
    let right = len - left

    " force the title with repeat() function and insert it in the buffer
    put=printf(&commentstring, repeat(commentChar, left) . commentText . repeat(commentChar, right))

endfunction
```

First the part where he gets the arguments:

```
    let commentText = get(a:000, 0, '')
```

According to [`:h function-argument`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#function-argument)
`a:000` is a dictionary containing all the arguments, then `a:000[0]` is
equivalent to `a:1`

The function `get()` third parameter is a default value.
This syntax allows to greatly reduce the ugly `if...else` structure that I
originally used.

Another cool trick is to use `printf(&commentstring, '')` to replace the `%s` part
of the string. Once again much cleaner than my `substitute` workaround

And finally the reason I used his function: the use of `repeat()`:

```
printf(&commentstring, repeat(commentChar, left) . commentText . repeat(commentChar, right))
```

The function repeat the expression passed as first parameter, the number of time
passed as second parameter and return the concatenated result. This way in a
single line two loops are written in a very readible format.

Many thanks to Peter for the improved version!

Comment: You could even use the utf-8 linedrawing characters: '╔═╗║╚═╝┌─┐│└─┘', If you want to create 'configuration'-files, that can also double as 'documentation', and will look like something to the boss, when he sees it printed on your wall. :)

Comment: May want to use `repeat()` instead of a loop. See `:h repeat()`

Comment: @PeterRincker nice function I didn't knew it. What is its advantage compared to a loop (excepted the fact that it requires less lines to write it)?

Comment: @statox there are 2 reasons to use repeat over a loop. 1) shorter 2) quick comprehension - instead of having to read and understand the loop, you can easily understand what is going on. As an example compare your function to [mine](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/6e16e5a82065d7f9809f).

Comment: @PeterRincker Indeed that's a great way to rewrite it! I'll investigate the `repeat` command which seems really good, thanks.

Comment: @statox please feel free to use it in your answer.

Comment: Erf I misclicked and removed my previous comment: to keep the history coherent I was asking to Peter if I could include part of his version to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is a perfect use case for [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) with Python interpolation.  A sketch of a snippet for the first header might look like this:

```
global !p
from math import floor, ceil

def left(lng, fill, s):
    count = int(floor((lng - len(s) - 6) / 2.0))
    if count < 0: count = 0
    return fill * count

def right(lng, fill, s):
    count = int(ceil((lng - len(s) - 6) / 2.0))
    if count < 0: count = 0
    return fill * count
endglobal

snippet com "Centered comments" b
//`!p snip.rv = left(80, '=', t[1])` ${1:Solving a big problem} `!p snip.rv = right(80, '=', t[1])`//
$0
endsnippet
```

Comment: I don't use utlisnipts but to sounds like a great idea to use it: that might be a good way not to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Since you're using Python anyway, try string formatting like in my post: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/585/205

Comment: @muru Well I'm afraid I have no idea how to do that.  The naive attempt `//\`!p snip.rv = '{:=^76}'.format(' ' + t[1] + ' ')\`//` doesn't work, and neither does `//\`!p snip.rv = '{:=^76}'.format(' ' + t[1] + ' ')\`${1:Solving a big problem}//`.  My knowledge of ultisnips is not up to the task, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

#### Just don't

I agree with @statox, "just don't do this". However if you do then @Sato Katsura is also correct that the best way is probably to use some snippets.

However if you do not want to use snippets here are some native Vim methods.

#### `'virtualedit'`

You can `:set virutaledit=all` to make it so you can insert text anywhere without worrying about pesky line lengths and spaces. This is great for ASCII art or making comment boxes (use `r`). Use `|` to jump to a specific column, e.g. `80|` to jump to column 80.

For more help see:

- [`:h 'virtualedit'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27virtualedit%27)
- [`:h r`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#r)
- [`:h |`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#bar)

#### Overwrite with `R`

Use the `R` command to replace/overwrite characters. This is a great way to put in your text without having to remove and tinker with your new comment line's length.

For more help see:

- [`:h R`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#R)

#### Use `:center`

The `:center` command will center text (by default to 80 chars). This isn't directly useful however you can use it to get your positioning without doing any hard work. Just create a line with your text then execute `:center`. Now that you know the starting column you can use `R` on your actual comment line. Bonus points for using `<c-r>` to paste the text.

For more help see:

- [`:h :center`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:center)
- [`:h i_CTRL-R`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R)

#### Re-centering

Re-centering can be accomplished using `:center`, `r`, `R`, and `<c-r>`. (All the `r`'s!)

Starting on the start of the word, do the following:

```
v/-\+/b-<cr>ygvr-O<c-r>0<esc>:center<cr>jR<c-r>0<esc>kdd
```

Probably best to make this a command or mapping. Note it has quite a few side-effects.

For more help see:

- [`:h r`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#r)
- [`:h R`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#R)
- [`:h i_CTRL-R`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R)
- [`:h O`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#O)
- [`:h :center`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:center)
- [`:h /`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/)
- [`:h search-offset`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#search-offset)
- [`:h registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers)
- [`:h quote0`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote0)
- [`:h :noh`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#:noh)

#### Re-centering with a substitution or "how I learned to abuse regex backtracking"

Another approach to re-centering is to use a substitution, `:s`, with a sub-replace-expression.

```
:s/\v(-+)(.{-})(-+)/\=substitute(submatch(1).submatch(3),'\v(-*)(\1-=)','\1'.escape(submatch(2),'&~').'\2','')/
```

**Overview**:

Capture the text and the leading and trailing characters, `-` in this case. We use a sub-replace-expression to do another substitution to divide up the dashes in half. This balancing act is done via the regex engine's backtracking because math is hard (let's go shopping).

Notes:

- Using very magic, `\v`, to simplify regex. See [`:h 'magic'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27magic%27).
- Using a sub-replace-expression, `\=`. See [`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression).
- `{-}` is a non-greedy version of `*`. Similar to `*?` in Perl-speak. See [`:h /\{-`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#E60).
- Learn more about this regex trick here: [An easy way to center text between first and last non-white word in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15844169/438329)
- Possibly use `:keeppatterns` to prevent side-effects.

Probably best to make this into a command:

```
:command! -range -bar CenterComment execute <line1>.','.<line2>.'s/\V\^'.printf(escape(&commentstring, '\/'), '\zs\(\.\=\)\(\1\*\)\(\.\{-}\)\(\1\*\)\ze')."\\$/\\=substitute(submatch(1).submatch(2).submatch(4),'\\v(.*)(\\1.=)','\\1'.escape(submatch(3),'&~').'\\2','')/"
```

Now you can just use `:CenterComment` on the comment line to recenter text.

For more help see:

- [`:h :s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s)
- [`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression)
- [`:h submatch()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#submatch())
- [`:h escape()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#escape())
- [`:h 'magic'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27magic%27)
- [`:h /\{-`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#E60)
- [`:h /\=`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C=)
- [`:h /\zs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Czs)
- [`:h :command`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command)
- [`:h printf()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#printf())
- [`:h 'commentstring'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27commentstring%27)

#### Thoughts

Once again, just don't worry about this. There are plenty other things to worry about, e.g. your code and quality of documentation.

Personally if I was going to use these kind of comments I would use some kind of snippet and `:CenterComment` command.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter implementation, interactive (will ask for the comment), inspired from the old-and-true [IBM "Vim Scripting" guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-vim-script-2/) (part 2, listings 13 & 14) and adapted for the OP request:

```
" ========= fancy comments ====================================================
" inspired from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-vim-script-2/
" (listings 13 & 14)
function! CommentBlock(comment, intro, end, box_char, ...)
    " linewdith is 1ist computed from the 'textwidth' if set, 80 if not
    let linewidth = &textwidth> 0? &textwidth : 80
    " but can be overwritten by the optional argument value:
    let linewidth = a:0 >= 1 ? a:1 : linewidth

    let comwidth = strlen(a:comment) + 2
    let boxwidth1 = (linewidth - comwidth - len(a:intro) - len(a:end)) / 2
    let boxwidth1 = boxwidth1>0 ? boxwidth1 : 0

    let boxwidth2 = (linewidth - len(a:intro) -len(a:end) - boxwidth1 - comwidth)
    return a:intro . repeat(a:box_char, boxwidth1) . ' ' . a:comment
                \ . ' ' .repeat(a:box_char, boxwidth2) . a:end
endfunction
```

No indentation support, though.

**Mapping example**:

```
inoremap <silent> //* <C-R>=CommentBlock(input("Comment> "), '//', '//', '*')<cr>
inoremap <silent> //= <C-R>=CommentBlock(input("Comment> "), '//', '//', '=')<cr>
inoremap <silent> //- <C-R>=CommentBlock(input("Comment> "), '//', '//', '-')<cr>
inoremap <silent> //x
            \ <C-R>=CommentBlock(input("Comment (40)> "), '/*', '*/',  'x', 40)<cr>
```

**Results**:

```
//******************************* hello world ********************************//
//============================ this is a comment? ============================//
//------------------------------ minus for you -------------------------------//
/*xxxxxxxxxxx asdfasdfasdf xxxxxxxxxxx*/
```