# How to conveniently add ornate headers to source code?

Tags: vimscript, formatting

Currently I’m adding source sections manually, e.g.:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 *                                entry point
 ******************************************************************************/
fn main () { println!("Hello World!"); }
```

The commands required to create this particular heading is quite
long:

```
0a*<ESC>oentry point<ESC>:ce<CR>kYjpr $r/kk0r/jl
```

For languages only supporting line comments the sequence is a bit shorter.

Once I have an initial section, I simply copy and paste it to create all
subsequent ones, which reduces the effort to find some header, past it to
where I need it, replace the label text, and re-center it.

**What would be a less pedestrian way to achieve this?**

Sectioning should employ the current comment character settings of the Nerd
Commenter plugin. Supplying their own list would be fine too.

No language specific plugins please.

Comment: Don't do that: your code doesn't need it and only create useless stuff which harden the reading. If you still really want to do that, check [a snippet manager plugin](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7466/1841). Also not a duplicate but [a strongly related question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4358/1841)

Comment: Also see: making a box using vimscript-python: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/585/205

Comment: @statox Structuring your source code is hardly “useless”. If anything the headers help a first-time reader to quickly apprehend how the file is structured.

Comment: A pedestrian way would be to solve the problem for a given language first.  As the pedestrian learns to mount VimL horses, he might evolve the solution by looking at `&comments` and `&textwidth` to make it language-independent (when possible, that is).

Comment: @phg: I agree with statox on this one. It does not add any *meaning* to the file, only a visual mark of something important. If a first time reader need to go through a file for the first time, it may rely on classes, functions, namespaces (depending on the languages). Those are useful for the program to run and for the reader to understand. If you find it hard to understand a commented code, you may want to try with a generated documentation, which purpose is to be read instead to grasp the purpose of the code.

Comment: @phg statox and nobe4 are right. I only use these kinds of comments as separators in large files. Even then it's a single line with a searchable prefix. Unless you are actually teaching or doing something unexpected, you should always assume the reader is familiar with the language. The only time large comment blocks are useful is when they're actually documenting something that isn't self explanatory.

Comment: @tommy-a “separators in large files” is exactly the use case, I thought that was obvious from the description.

Comment: @phg I meant to add "for purpose specific code", like "text utilities" and "image processing" if they have to be in the same file.  I also said I use a single line with a searchable prefix, like `//// text utilities`. Your example looks like you want function banners.

Comment: @TommyA For what it's worth: comments starting with `TODO`, `FIXME`, or `XXX` are highlighted specially by Vim.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Those are definitely good for notes. I forgot where I read about it, but another useful way is to use something like `//?` for section headings so you can list them with `:g#^//?#p`.

Answer (score 8):

***Note 1** As I said in the comment this kind of box is not a good thing: it distract the eye from the important part of your file (the comment itself or the actual code). There are better way to create headers. Now this is only my opinion and this site is not here to argue about this so here is a solution.*

***Note 2** I give here a solution with the plugins I know but you could probably use any snippet manager other than Ultisnips.*

***Note 3** Using a snippet manager only for this snippet is probably overkill and you should probably considering creating your own vimscript function. For example, here is [an answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4358/1841) I made (with a **great** help from @Peter Rincker) for a similar question. It uses only vimscript and creates headers a little lighter.*

---

What you are looking for is an intelligent snippet, it is also a built-in feature of Ultisnips + vim-snippets:

First, install [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) which is a snippet engine (it will allow you to work with snippets but doesn't provide the snippets themselves).

Then you have two ways to get the snippet you're looking for:

**Method 1** You can install [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) which provides a whole list of predefined snippets.

**Method 2** You can declare the snippet by yourself (which is a little bit more work but is lighter since you get only the snippet you need):

First create a file `~/.vim/my-snippets/Ultisnips/all.snippets`.

Then in this file add this:

```
global !p
def make_box(twidth, bwidth=None):
    b, m, e, i = (s.strip() for s in get_comment_format())
    bwidth_inner = bwidth - 3 - max(len(b), len(i + e)) if bwidth else twidth + 2
    sline = b + m + bwidth_inner * m[0] + 2 * m[0]
    nspaces = (bwidth_inner - twidth) // 2
    mlines = i + m + " " + " " * nspaces
    mlinee = " " + " "*(bwidth_inner - twidth - nspaces) + m
    eline = i + m + bwidth_inner * m[0] + 2 * m[0] + e
    return sline, mlines, mlinee, eline

def get_comment_format():
    """ Returns a 4-element tuple (first_line, middle_lines, end_line, indent)
    representing the comment format for the current file.

    It first looks at the 'commentstring', if that ends with %s, it uses that.
    Otherwise it parses '&comments' and prefers single character comment
    markers if there are any.
    """
    commentstring = vim.eval("&commentstring")
    if commentstring.endswith("%s"):
        c = commentstring[:-2]
        return (c, c, c, "")
    comments = _parse_comments(vim.eval("&comments"))
    for c in comments:
        if c[0] == "SINGLE_CHAR":
            return c[1:]
    return comments[0][1:]
endglobal

snippet box "A nice box with the current comment symbol" b
`!p
box = make_box(len(t[1]))
snip.rv = box[0]
snip += box[1]
`${1:content}`!p
box = make_box(len(t[1]))
snip.rv = box[2]
snip += box[3]`
$0
endsnippet
```

The part in the `global/endglobal` are python helper function made to create a box and get the comment character for the buffer. The part in the `snippet/endsnippet` is the actual snippet using the python interpolations.

Then independently from the method you followed, you simply have to type `box` and then use the key you defined in your vimrc to trigger a snippet and the box will be created. You'll then enter insert mode allowing you to type the text you want to put in a box, the length of the box will be updated while you enter the text.

**Note** that I didn't create the code in this answer, it comes directly from the vim-snippets directory [here](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/pythonx/vimsnippets.py) and [here](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/all.snippets)

---

Some interesting resources about snippets:

- I asked [a question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7466/1841) to differentiate the different snippets managers. As long as you choose snipmate compatible snippets engines, the one I gave you should work.
- Vimcast made [some good episodes](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-ultisnips/) about Ultisnips.
- And of course [the ultisnip doc](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 7):

I actually wrote a blog post about this:

http://rainymood.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/06/25/vim-macro.html

tl;dr use a Vim Macro

Macro used for the image below

```
qai###<Esc>A<Esc><Space>###<Esc>YppkkVR#jjVR#q
```

[image]

You could probably do something similar

Comment: This doesn’t expand to ``textwidth`` for one. Also, seems like it’s quite language specific

Comment: @phg You're trying too hard to make the problem a pain in the rear for the potential answerers.

Comment: @phb you are correct. I have to note that I never said it would expand to `textwidth`. I merely wanted to show a solution that I hacked together which I think might solve OP's problem fairly quickly (i.e. simple use of a vim macro)

Answer (score 4):

## `!!boxes`

Another solution is filtering the line through the command line tool [(ascii-)`boxes`](http://boxes.thomasjensen.com/)

```
!!boxes -s 72 -d c
```

or use visual selection

```
'<,'>!boxes -s 72 -d c
```

- `-s 72` size of box
- `-d c` select box type (design); here the c box; to see box designs run `$ boxes -l`

`boxes` can be installed via homebrew/linuxbrew and linux distro packages, e.g. debian (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/boxes) and ubuntu (http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/boxes).

*Note*
However, I agree boxes can reduce code readability. Use them wisely.

Comment: ``boxes`` looks really great, thanks for the recommendation. However, despite its comprehensive website and manpage I couldn’t make it accept a triple of strings---start, middle, end---to create the box. Also, to use it in a sufficiently flexible manner one would still have to pass it the info in Vim’s ``comments`` variable in some fashion (via custom box designs, most likely). So IMO it doesn’t beat drawing those boxes with a plugin.

Comment: The author of boxes has created a [Text Editor integration](http://boxes.thomasjensen.com/docs/install.html) website. There are given mappings for certain FileType events with a common keybinding. If all design names are chose accordingly to filetype names, this could be simplified, also optionally incorporating the value from `&textwidth`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little script, to block the selected texts with customized characters. well it is not yet valid C/java comment, however it shouldn't be hard to adjust. Take a look if it helps:

https://github.com/sk1418/blockit

the Readme includes gif animation and introductions.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with my own script: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7878a79fccc74bbc00db6cf0c330c23f

It parses `&comments` to generate a formatted block
with separators expanded to `&textwidth`. By default,
Leaderh inserts the block while
in insert and normal mode.

Since `comments` is a bit weird to process, the script
will output garbage for certain values. But it’s been
tweaked enough to work for the ones that matter to me
personally.